# What is the difference between the classifiers 册 and 本?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

租借小人书很便宜，在摊里看，每册1分钱，选好书坐下就看，看完连书带钱交给摊主；假如借走回家看，则每本每天2分钱，挑好书后交给摊主，...

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 20. What is the difference between the classifiers 册 and 本?

在摊里看，每册1分钱

在摊里看，每本1分钱

则每册每天2分钱

则每本每天2分钱

一册书

一本书

一册本

一本册

一册杂志

一本杂志

Answer (score 2):

本 can be generally applied to books, that is, objects that consist of pages between two covers.

册 is also applied to books, but it usually emphasizes that the said book is part of a larger series. For example, the two parts of a two-part book are usually called 上册, 下册.

If a multi-volume work is divided into "volumes" and each volume is divided into "parts" (like the Cambridge Histories), then use 卷 for each volume and 册 for each part.

For 杂志 (magazine), we usually use 一本杂志 or 一期杂志, 一册杂志 is relatively rare.

Answer (score 0):

Supplement:
1.

"租借小人书很便宜，在摊里看，每册1分钱，选好书坐下就看，看完连书带钱交给摊主；假如借走回家看，则每本每天2分钱，挑好书后交给摊主"   In this context, **册and本 share the same meaning.**
Generally speaking, using 册 can be more proper for 册 always indicates a thinner book than 本

2.
一册书 can indicate **a series of books with the same theme**, like 《Oxford Bookworms》, while 一本书 only means a single book.

3.
When being used as nouns, **一本册 is right in grammar**, meaning 'a book'(usually thin) However, **一册本 is wrong**.